# Misleading Pearson Correlation Coefficient?

Tags: correlation

I'm looking at the correlation between day of week and number of page views my website gets.  Because day of week is a discrete, non-numeric variable, I've mapped Sunday to 0, Monday to 1, ..., Saturday to 6.

Here's my concern / question: Isn't it possible to get a low Pearson coefficient when, in fact, there is a relationship between day of week and page views, it's just a bit more complicated.

For example, it might be that Mondays and Fridays are highly correlated with page views and the middle of the week is negatively correlated.  So this might average out to a correlation near 0 when there's a real pattern there.

Is there a standard way of trying to figure out what's going on here?  My mapping of days to numbers seems simplistic...

Thanks!

Comment: A correlation does not make sense here, because your coded variable of the day-of-the-week is not quantitative (doesn't make sense to take an average). I would just look at a table of values. There might be some mixed methods you could use, though.